# My simple and configurable products are imported without errors but the simple are not attached to the configurable

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, import, associate-products

Associated products do not show in the configurable product, don't know why... though My simple and configurable products are imported without errors but the simple are not attached to the configurable.

All conditions are checked by me..

```
visibilty = not show inidividually
stock = in stock
attribute set in simple =  same as configurable product
price =  set
status = enable
```

re-indexing -> done ...

I am using the DataFlow import tool..

Comment: Please share your product import csv file with two or 3 configure and its child product.

Comment: its .xml file....

Comment: Now successfully done... there is small mistake related to attributes in simple products.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to associate simple products to configurable parents using the 'data flow' import tool.

As you are using Magento 1.9.x you can use the more advanced Magento 'ImportExport' system under '**System > Import/Export > Import**'.

See more detail about the Magento 'ImportExport' system on the official documentation pages here: http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/data-import.html

And guidelines for importing here: http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/store-operations/data-import-guidelines.html

For more information about the format required to import (as it is considerably different from 'data flow') I would suggest exporting an existing configurable product with associations as reference or read up on articles such as this: https://www.integer-net.com/importing-products-with-the-import-export-interface/